# How make a pane visible on top in qt quick application?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to show a Message bar for showing my messages to users,be visible on top of all other windows and pages?

**MessageBar.qml**

```
Pane {
id: bar
z: 9999999999999999

property alias message:me
Message{
    id: me
    onContentChanged: {
    }
}
Material.background: message.backColor
height: 48

Label{
    color: "white"
    text: message.content
    anchors.fill: parent
    horizontalAlignment: Label.AlignHCenter
}
property bool visibleState: message.visible&&message.messageType== Message.SimpleMessage
scale: visibleState?1.0:0.0
Behavior on scale {
    NumberAnimation {
        duration: 100
    }
}
```

}

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow { 
    MessageBar{
    id: messageBar
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    }    
}
```

but it will be visible under other pages how solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean saying "on top of all other windows and pages"? What pages? If you ask about OS windows you have to create `Window` with flag [Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum#WindowType-enum).If that windows inside the same application you have to take into account that `z` works only for siblings items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a `Popup`. These are shown above all other items in the scene by default. In addition, you can set a popup's [`z`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#z-prop) value to ensure that it's above all other popups.

If you don't want to use a popup for some reason, you can parent the item to the [overlay](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-overlay.html):

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "Button"
    }

    Pane {
        width: 200
        height: 200
        parent: Overlay.overlay
        Material.background: Material.Grey

        Label {
            text: "Above"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```