# Overlay Qml Widget on top of Ui form

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, overlay

For **QtQuick** Application I can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418092/how-make-a-pane-visible-on-top-in-qt-quick-application). But my intention is to use Qml Overlay on some old projects of mine (**QtWidgets** application).

I have tried to use `centralWidget` of my Window as container of my new `QmlWidget` like this:

*mainwindow.cpp*:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Load QML overlay
    qmlWidget = new QQuickWidget();
    qmlWidget->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Overlay.qml")));

    // Set the position of the QML widget on the UI
    qmlWidget->setGeometry(50, 50, 50, 50);

    // Add the QML widget to the layout
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(qmlWidget);
    qmlWidget->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

*Overlay.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: overlayRect
    parent: Overlay.overlay
    x: 0; y: 0
    width: 50; height: 50
    color: "red"
}
```

But this results in application crash.

Then I tried to make some kind of layout myself and it worked but not the way I wanted. So when I added a `VerticalLayout` (and filled it with some `QPushButtons`) and changed line:

```
ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(qmlWidget);
```

in my *mainwindow.cpp* to be:

```
//ui->vl is the VerticalLayout
ui->vl->addWidget(qmlWidget);
```

I got the next result:

[image: Result]

And to be more clear, what I wanted is to specify where I want my `qmlWidget` like this:

```cpp
qmlWidget->setGeometry(50, 50, 50, 50);
```